# Synonymize tag [isa] to [instruction-set]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I read through the questions tagged [isa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isa). The acronym may potentially be ambiguous.

Of 176 questions, I retagged

- ~ 10 questions to [isaserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isaserver) (37 questions) related to [Microsoft ISA Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront_Threat_Management_Gateway) a now rebranded thing, but tag already existed and the questions was from around 2011.
- 3 questions to [isa-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isa-bus) that was about the [ISA Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture)

The remaining questions tagged [isa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isa) (162 questions) is tagged for the same meaning as tag [instruction-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set) (452 questions) both related to [Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture). I propose that tag [isa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isa) should be synonymized with [instruction-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set) so that the questions about the same thing is under the same tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [isa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isa) tag has now been renamed to [instruction-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set) to reduce ambiguity.

Before commencing the rename, I also fixed a couple of question that you had missed. These were mainly questions about Perl's `isa` function (of which there were only perhaps 3 in total, and I don't think that needs a dedicated tag at this point), and Microsoft's old "Internet Security and Acceleration Server", formerly known as "ISA Server", now known as [Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront_Threat_Management_Gateway) (I don't think there is a replacement tag, but most questions about this were very old and of dubious topicality).